# localStorage like storage alternatives for HTA

Tags: javascript, local-storage, hta

I am developing a HTA application, for that I need to store some data at client side using JavaScript. Like localStorage in HTML5, I am just looking for same functionality if possible. Please let me know if I can found any.

Answer (score 9):

In HTA you are free to use any ActiveX you want. `FileSystemObject` is the best solution for simple folder and file actions, though it can read and write text files only. With this ActiveX Control you can also create and delete folders and files, retrieve their properties etc.

FSO and HTAs are still working in IE9. However, all development and support was ended at IE7, so all HTML and JavaScript capabilites (and bugs) are on that level too. To utilize features available to IE9, use `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">` in `<head>`. This works with single pages only, and can't be used within `frameset`-pages.

FileSystemObject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51%28v=vs.84%29.aspx
HyperText-Applications: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536471%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**Basic functions in FileSystemObject**

Create an ActiveX:

```
fso=new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
```

Write a file:

```
var oStream=fso.OpenTextFile('SAVE_PATH',2,true);
oStream.WriteLine('YOUR_DATA'); // Usually looped for several lines
oStream.Close();
```

Open a file:

```
var iStream=fso.OpenTextFile('OPEN_PATH',1,false);
data=iStream.ReadLine(); // Usually looped for several lines
iStream.Close();
```

See also `WScript.Shell`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98591fh7%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it still works with newer IE versions (>6), but you can try the FileSystemObject ActiveX component.

Answer (score 1):

In hta, you can sotre your data into Microsoft Access *.mdb.  [see this](http://www.vistax64.com/vb-script/176153-hta-file-display-data-db-records-table-like-asp-how.html)
or you can use Google Gears for mysql support.