# Write to a text file using an HTA

Tags: hta

I am trying to create an HTA file that allows a user to add data to a text file. I am fairly Inexperienced in the area.

I need to accomplish a few things:

1. Write the bit of data that is inputted to a text file (which my code does)
2. Let the user chose from a drop-down list of available files to write to
3. It would be nice if the data could be submitted onClick or by hitting Enter
4. Clear the fields on submit
5. Log every entry. No overwriting of data in the text file (my code overwrites)

example:

123
456
789

I apologize if my code looks choppy.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thank you.

```
<html><head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

    Sub Window_onLoad
        window.resizeTo 480,150
    End Sub 

</SCRIPT>
<script language="javascript">
function Writedata()
{
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var write_id;
write_id = document.getElementById('write_id').value ;
alert('The data has been written to \n' + write_id);
var s = fso.CreateTextFile(write_id, true);

s.WriteLine(document.getElementById('name_id').value);

s.Close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
<td>Input: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name_id"></td>
<td><select><option name="write" value="C:\temp\test1.txt" id="write_id">Option1</option>    </select></td>
<td><input type="button" onclick="Writedata()" value="submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can check [this my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9686960/1169519), there's basic functions for reading and writing files, and also some useful links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you've edited your code. Though it can be more flexible:

`var s = fso.CreateTextFile(write_id, true);` maybe rather:

```
var s = fso.OpenTextFile(write_id, 2, true);
```

where `2` represents a bytecode:
`1` = read, `2` = write, `8` = append.

`write_Id` should contain a full path to file, like `D:/Foldername/filename.txt`.

---

That's not how you should use `select`, rather give the `id` for `select` itself like this:

```
<select id="write_id">
    <option value="C:\temp\test1.txt">Option1</option>
</select>
```

Now the value of selected `option` is stored also as value of `select`, which you can read in your script exactly like you are doing now.

Also you can declare a variable and assign a value together in JS:

```
var write_id = document.getElementById('write_id').value;
```

Comment: That helps. 'var s = fso.OpenTextFile(write_id, 8, true);' It is now appending rather than overwriting.

Comment: Any thoughts on the Drop-down menu for selecting the file to write to?

Comment: I'm not sure what you need, populate `select` element from a file? Submitting HTA data, where?. [`form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/form) element has [`reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/form.reset) method to reset all its inputs. Please check [`onkeyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/keyup) for hitting `ENTER`. BTW you can get rid off VBScript, just add `window.resizeTo(480,150)` to JS section.

Comment: The only thing I am having trouble with now is the form reset for some reason. I am not sure what I'm missing.