# How to write form value to local text file?

Tags: html, vbscript, text-files, hta

I'm creating an hta file that will only ever be run on my local machine. When I input a value into the form field and click the submit button, I'd like the value to overwrite any other text within the file C:\data.txt . I can't figure out why this won't work.. (I've read many similar posts with no luck)

This is the relevant HTML I have:

```
<input type="text" name="Keyword" value="">
<input type="button" value="Submit!" class="myButton" onClick="SaveData">
```

and here is the script I'm using:

```
<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">
    Sub SaveData
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If objFSO.FileExists("C:\data.txt") Then
           Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\data.txt", 8)
            strLine = Keyword.Value & vbTab
            objFile.WriteLine strLine
            objFile.Close
        Else
            Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\data.txt")
            strLine = keyword.Value & vbTab
            objFile.WriteLine strLine
            objFile.Close
        End If
    End Sub

</SCRIPT>-->
```

The script sits just above the < body > tag. Why is no file created when I click the submit button? Thank you!!

Comment: Why is this tagged JavaScript/jQuery when it is VBScript?

Comment: Your script works fine for me. Does it throw any error for you?

Comment: "just above the < body >"? If it's between `head` and `body`, move it to either element. Is `vbTab` defined at the time you're running the script? Do you have JavaScript on the page, it might "steal" the event handling. `-->` after the ending script tag tells, that you've a `<!--`  _before_  the start tag? If so, remove the comment markup. Or at least move it _into_ script. Where are you submitting the form?

Comment: Can you post the hole HTA ?

Comment: Since you have not put in any error traps, I suspect that Windows is preventing file creations on C:\. Can you try create the file somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks guys, here's the link to my site which shows the same code my hta does. http://testsite24.netai.net/public/test.html   When I open the html locally in Chrome, and I submit a keyword it doesn't create any file! The keyword just sits there... What's wrong?   @ PatricK, I tried to write to E: drive too which is external USB and no luck. Thanks!!

Comment: In Chrome??? HTAs or VBScript are not working in Chrome. HTAs are run by mshta.exe, and need Internet Explorer to be installed to work. Also they must be saved with `.hta` extension, not `.htm(l)`.

Comment: Forget I even mentioned an HTA, this html file I posted should write a local text file but it's not. Why not?

Comment: Only in Internet Explorer when you expand the options to allow ActiveX. Where is vbTab defined? It seems to cause an error.

Comment: Are you saying that an HTML file can't write a local text file unless it's done through IE? That seems absurd. Also, I'm not sure if vbTab is defined, or how to do so.. can you look at my source code and tell me where to do it? Thanks Teemu

Comment: I've run the html file locally using IE 11 and allowed ActiveX, and it still wont' write the text file. Please help, my site is here:  testsite24.netai.net/public/test.html

Comment: @ Teemu: I found a post you replied to which helped me solve the issue here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324634/write-to-a-text-file-using-an-hta   Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try using JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function SaveData(){
          var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
          fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\data.txt");
          var myfile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\data.txt", 2, true);
          myfile.writeLine(Keyword.value);
          myfile.Close();
     }
</script>
```