# In a Html Application, using javascript, how would I get an image's position on the screen an put it in a text document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hta

I have several images, with different id's, that use the jquery ui draggble div code:

```
$( function() {
$( "#t" ).draggable();
} );
```

How do I get the x and y coordinates (left: px;top: px; in css) that the image is on and put it in a text document?

Comment: Part 1: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop . Part 2: where is this text file? You can't amend files on the user's disk from a browser.  You could maybe create a file and offer it for download, with a bit of mucking about. Probably an example online somewhere.

Comment: To read/write to a textfile with HTA, you can use [ActiveX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51(v=vs.84).aspx), see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9686960/1169519) for basic usage. @ADyson With HTA it is possible to access user's filesystem almost wiithout restrictions.

Comment: @Teemu True, I had not spotted the HTA tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery UI, you have the position of the element on the "stop" event, which is triggered when the drag stops.

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
  stop: function( event, ui ) {
    // Here, on the ui object, you have both position and offset
    // See below for an explanation of the difference
  }
});
```

For retrieving the position of the element, **relative to the offset parent**, you should use the `position()` api. If you want the position relative **to the document**, you should use the `offset()` api.

jquery docs :

> When positioning a new element on top of an existing one for global
>   manipulation (in particular, for implementing drag-and-drop),
>   .offset() is more useful.

in both case, you can use the dot syntax to get a specific direction offset or position :

```
$('#test').offset().left;
$('#test').offset().top;
// -----
$('#test').position().left;
$('#test').position().top;
```

For storing that information to a file, you may need an API where you send the data via an ajax call, and then do the file writing stuff (help here depend on the backend tech you choose).

Comment: The filesystem of the user's machine is the backend tech in this case.