# HTA loading content into div without AJAX Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, hta

I have an HTA which I am trying to load html content into from an external file. The method of choice is AJAX but unfortunately you cant do that in an HTA. However, I have found a pure javascript method for doing this but I keep getting access denied at the line request.open. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en-US">
  <head>
  <title>test file</title>
  <hta:application id="test app">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"> 
  </script> 
  <script type="text/javascript"  charset="utf8" src="resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"  charset="utf8" src="resources/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/navigation.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/scroller.dataTables.min.css">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">    
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">      
  </head>
 <body>
 <div class="header"></div>
<input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu">
<label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
 <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
 <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
 <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
</label>
<div id="sidebarMenu">
 <ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
   <li><a href="#" id ="ajaxjestid" target="_blank">nav1</a></li>
</ul>
</div>    

<div id="ajaxtest"></div>
<!-- Footer -->
<footer >
<script language="javascript">
function myFunction() {
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'resources/html/ajaxtest.html', true);
request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        var resp = request.responseText;
        document.querySelector('#div').innerHTML = resp;
}
};
request.send();
}

$('#ajaxjestid').click(function(){ myFunction(); return false; });

</script>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is ajax. What am I missing here?

Comment: Note if you are loading the file straight from your filesystem, ie the url will start with `file:///` you wont be able to use ajax as it isnt allowed when viewing pages from the filesystem(security measure)

Comment: Yea i meant AJAX jquery which would use the load function but Patrick that is helpful. I guess I cannot do it then.

Comment: Patrick, does a network drive still count as a local file system ? I’m assuming yes but just curious.

Comment: Use ActiveX to read local files in HTAs. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9686960/1169519 and follow the MSDN links in that post too.

Comment: So I have used FSO previously in VBS and VBA but appending the HTA file real time

Comment: @teemu how long do you think hta files will be supported? Also, I noticed hta tag is no longer supported but is vbscript still supported even if content is set to ie=edge?

Comment: HTAs haven't been supported since IE10, setting `IE=9` makes the `<HTA>` tag work, but downgrades the DOM and JS also to the level of IE9. VBS for web apps was dropped in IE10, but it still works on local apps, also in IE11.

Comment: @teemu we are stuck to local development and cannot install any additional software so HTAs are a really good option. I only worry longevity. We use windows 10 now but I know we will want this hta program to work for atleast 5 years. Does that seem realistic?

Comment: @Teemu do you think it’s safe to assume hta’s will still run even in five years from now?

Comment: I don't know, it's tough to make predictions, especially about the future. You could ask Microsoft for this, they know better.